# Ошибка 500 не связанная с .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

[image: Ошибка]

На сайте нет файла .htaccess (проблем с кодировкой не было, решил не добавлять), из за которого происходит **ошибка 500**. Я не могу понять что именно не так. Ни кого *сообщения* или *лога ошибки* нет. На локальном хостинге **всё работает**. На скрине видно что html начал грузится, так как была подгружена иконка на вкладке сайта. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Иконка на вкладке к html никакого отношения не имеет и грузится отдельно

Comment: Логирование на сервере включите и повторите попытку.

Comment: Пришлите выдержку из error_log. Без него любой совет - пальцем в небо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Ошибка 500 не обязательно должна быть связана с файлом ".htaccess". Данная ошибка просто обозначает, что на сервере произошло что - то не то. Может ли быть проблема в php - скрипте? 
2) Возможно ли, что Ваш хостинг сам добавил файл ".htaccess" и ошибку генерирует именно он? 
3) Я не уверен на счёт Nginx, но в Apache точно есть логи. Можете ли Вы проверить их, если они присутствуют?

Comment: Есть но они пусты(

Comment: Ошибка не на хостинге, я сейчас проверил работоспособность на хостинге fozzy, та же самая ситуация. Я даже понять не могу в чем может быть проблема. Все скрипты исправны. Как php так и js.